# ImageView zoom in and zoom out with Button click issue in Android

Tags: android

I have developed an application where there is an ImageView and inside the ImageView I have drawn a circle with Canvas in onDraw() method. For the first time (when the Zoom in Zoom out is not done) I am able to click the circle and display a message. However, when I zoomed in on the ImageView the circle also gets zoomed and changes its position, at that time when I clicked the circle, message is not displayed. I know that when the image is zoomed, the circle also get zoomed but it's position remains the same. Hence it's not get clicked. I don't know how to check and get the new position of the circle when the image gets zoomed. Any ideas/suggestion? Please reply.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get accomplished?  For the Circle' new position, I think what you need to do is perform a translation between canvas coordinates, and screen coordinates.  The Canvas (logical) size really isnt changing, but it's pixel size and potentially position within it's scroll parent are most likely changing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Logic as you said is absolutely fine. But I don't have any idea how to perform the translation. After zooming the position of the circle changes as per the zoom level, but it actually placed in it's original position. Don't know how to change it's original position to the zoomed level position. Please provide some more suggestion. Thanks.